# How long does it take to get a passport returned during re-evaluation of UK application?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, application-status

I know the timing of return of a passport is about 20 working days for a standard visitor visa application. I am unable to see on any forum an example of the timing of return of passport after a complaint was accepted and the application re-evaluated. Would it be the same 20 working days or a different time frame.

This is not anxiety; I genuinely want to know if anyone has an idea of how long it takes.

Comment: It's the same or might even take longer

Answer (score 2):

After an initial refusal, and a successful request for reconsideration, the UKVI does not have a separate or accelerated timeframe for processing applications. Your earlier questions suggest that it was about a month ago that additional documents were submitted, and one week ago that the passports were sent, upon request.

While most [applications from Pakistan](https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/karachi-pakistan/visits-visas/general-visit-6-months-or-less) are decided within about two weeks, there are those that can take as long as 60 days. Mind you, processing times do not include weekends or public holidays; discount those and the decision could take as long as 3 months. It just takes as long as it takes and, hopefully, the outcome will be favorable.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it took 2 weeks for the Passport to return with approval.